# Parallel loading of different instances of the same UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I have an html file that exposes a function that configures it with different data. I want three instances of this html in three different UIWebViews. It seems that doing so in parallel doesn't work, while if I create one instance at time (with a callback for when it's done) it works.
Any idea?

Comment: How are you creating them 'in parallel'?

Comment: and what are you trying to do with the html? I mean, I suppose you could set up 3 UIWebViews on 3 different queues and try to start them at the same time (about the same, don't think you can guarantee they will be be exactly synchronous)